# Date and time text boxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning RoR and trying to replace the default 5 drop down list controls generated for a datetime field from scaffolding to two textboxes, one for date and another for time.

In my example I run the following command to generate a Posts resource:

```
rails g scaffold post name:string content:text published_at:datetime
```

[image]

I've made the following changes so far:

*post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :published_at_date, :published_at_time

  after_initialize :get_datetimes
  before_validation :set_datetimes

  def get_datetimes
    self.published_at ||= Time.now

    self.published_at_date ||= self.published_at.to_date.to_s(:db)
    self.published_at_time ||= "#{'%02d' % self.published_at.hour}:#{'%02d' % self.published_at.min}"
  end

  def set_datetimes
    self.published_at = "#{self.published_at_date} #{self.published_at_time}:00"
  end  
end
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :name, :published_at, :published_at_date, :published_at_time)
  end
  ....
end
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  ....
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :published_at %><br>

    <%= f.text_field :published_at_date, :size => 10, :maxlength => 10 %>
    <%= f.text_field :published_at_time, :size => 5, :maxlength => 5 %>
  </div>
  ....
<% end %>
```

This displays the 2 textboxes as required, however, if I modify the date/time, the newly created Post ignores these and sets the published_at, published_at_date and published_at_time to the current datetime.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have validation in the Post model so maybe the callback `before_validation` is skipped. Try with `before_save`.

Besides, I suggest to convert the String to DateTime in `set_datetimes` method:

```
def set_datetimes
  self.published_at = DateTime.new("#{self.published_at_date} #{self.published_at_time}:00")
end
```